# See Optional Slots when buying ships

Tags: elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-horizons

I might be blind, but I've looked all over the interface and did a fair amount of Googling, so forgive me if I'm missing something?

Is there a way to see the optional slot **capacity** when purchasing a ship in-game?

For example, the Hauler shows in the Shipyard for purchase with the following:

- 2E Cargo Rack
- 2E Cargo Rack
- 2E Shield Generator

However, its actual capacity is 3, 3, 2, 1. It can handle 2x size 3, but it doesn't even list its size 1 slot. I can't find a way to tell that it actually has that without purchasing or checking online.

Comment: I didn't mean to accept this edit, my finger slipped. Feel free to revert the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the in-game view only shows you the modules that are equipped on the ship at the time you buy it. It doesn't show empty slots or higher tier slots filled with lower tier gear.

The only accurate way to get a list of all slots and their tiers is to check online.

Comment: That's what I figured, but thanks for the answer.